# tf.subtract cost too long time for large array

Tags: tensorflow

The Tensorflow tf.subtract cost too long time for the large array.

My workstation configuration:

CPU: Xeon E5 2699 v3
 Mem: 384 GB
 GPU: NVIDIA K80
 CUDA: 8.5
 CUDNN: 5.1
 Tensorflow: 1.1.0, GPU version

The following is the test code and result.

```
  import tensorflow as tf
  import numpy as np
  import time

  W=3000
  H=4000

  in_a = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,(W,H))
  in_b = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,(W,H))

  def test_sub(number):
      sess=tf.Session()
      out = tf.subtract(in_a,in_b)

      for i in range(number):          
          a=np.random.rand(W,H)
          b=np.random.rand(W,H)
          feed_dict = {in_a:a,
                       in_b:b}
          t0=time.time()
          out_ = sess.run(out,feed_dict=feed_dict)
          t_=(time.time()-t0) * 1000
          print "index:",str(i), " total time:",str(t_)," ms"  

  test_sub(20)
```

Results:
index: 0  total time: 338.145017624  ms
index: 1  total time: 137.024879456  ms
index: 2  total time: 132.538080215  ms
index: 3  total time: 133.152961731  ms
index: 4  total time: 132.885932922  ms
index: 5  total time: 135.06102562   ms
index: 6  total time: 136.723041534  ms
index: 7  total time: 137.926101685  ms
index: 8  total time: 133.605003357  ms
index: 9  total time: 133.143901825  ms
index: 10  total time: 136.317968369  ms
index: 11  total time: 137.830018997  ms
index: 12  total time: 135.458946228  ms
index: 13  total time: 132.793903351  ms
index: 14  total time: 144.603967667  ms
index: 15  total time: 134.593963623  ms
index: 16  total time: 135.535001755  ms
index: 17  total time: 133.697032928  ms
index: 18  total time: 136.134147644  ms
index: 19  total time: 133.810043335  ms

The test result shows it(i.e., tf.subtract) cost more than 130 ms to dispose a 3000x4000 subtraction, which obviously is too long, especially on the NVIDIA k80 GPU platform.

Can anyone provide some methods to optimize the tf.subtract?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You're measuring not only the execution time of `tf.subtract` but also the time required from transferring the input data from the CPU memory to the GPU memory: this is your bottleneck.

To avoid it, don't use placeholders to feed the data but generate it with tensorflow (if you have to randomly generate it) or if you have to read them, use the tensorflow input pipeline. (that creates threads that reads the input for you before starting and then feed the graph without exiting from the tensorflow graph)

It's important to do more possible operations within the tensorflow graph in order to remove the data transfer bottleneck.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds reasonable that the time I measured contained the data transferring time from CPU memory to GPU memory.

Since I have to read the input data (e.g., the input data are images generated by mobile phone and they are sent to the tensorflow one by one), does it mean that the tensorflow placeholders must be used?

To the situation mentioned above (the input data are images generated by mobile phone and they are sent to the tensorflow one by one), if two images are not generated at the same time (i.e., the second image comes long after the first one), how can the input pipeline threads read the input data before starting (i.e., the second image are not generated when the tensorflow is disposing the first image)? So, could you give me a simple example to explain the tensorflow input pipeline?